# Location service going to “Inactive” state in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location

I am creating an app which tracks user. When user login to app I have started significant Location updates. Then i put my application in background. and then started traveling with my car. After 500m-1km I got significant location change. On getting update I have stopped significant location updates and started standard GPS. it gives m location updates for 2-3 min after that i see this **"Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'"** and my app does not get any location updates.

If app is foregrounded then again app starts getting location updates.

I am using shared location instance. I have iPhone 5 and iOS 8.1.3. I am using Swift.

Adding some code.. I have done like this

```
    gpsManager = CLLocationManager()
            gpsManager.delegate = self
            gpsManager.desiredAccuracy = kaccuracy
            gpsManager.distanceFilter = kdistanceFilter 
            gpsManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
            gpsManager.headingFilter = kheadingFilter
            gpsManager.activityType = kactivityType

            isTracking = false
            isMonitoringSignificantChanges = false


           //on login 
         var sharedGPSManager=GeoLocation.sharedInstance
        sharedGPSManager.delegate=self
        let status=sharedGPSManager.authorizationStatus()
        if(status == 0)
        {

            NSLog("Allowed to track")
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("Not allowed")
        }
       sharedGPSManager.startSignificantLocationTracking()


     func gpsManager(manager:GeoLocation, didUpdateLocations locations:AnyObject)
    {
       var sharedGPSManager=GeoLocation.sharedInstance

        sharedGPSManager.stopSignificantLocationTracking()

     task=UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithName("wifiUpload", expirationHandler: { () -> Void in
        }


        sharedGPSManager.delegate = self
        let status = sharedGPSManager.authorizationStatus()
        if(status == 0)
        {
            NSLog("Allowed to track")
        }
       else
        {
            NSLog("Not allowed")
        }

        sharedGPSManager.startTracking()

         //process location data

       endBackgroundTask(task)
}
```

// Start location tracking
    func startTracking(){

```
    if(isMonitoringSignificantChanges){
        gpsManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    gpsManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable()
    {
        gpsManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    gpsManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    isTracking=true
    isMonitoringSignificantChanges=false
}
```

Comment: If you want location manager to listen forever then switch on app capabilities to receive location in background

Comment: No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)): begging, thanks and your name should never be part of a good question.

Comment: Could you share some code of what you do once you receive the first location which you have received in background. My guess is you turn off location services itself

Comment: when i receive first location update I stop significant location service and start Standard location service as shown in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the Answer on Apple developer forum.keeping significant Location always on worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Location Update` capability in background mode

Project Target > Capabilities > Turn Background mode **ON** > Tick all which is applicable for your app

[image]

Comment: I have already enabled Location updates in background modes. Also i have added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in plist. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Required background modes in info.plist as "App registers for location updates" then your application will give you location updates in background.

And you have to use `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` not the significant Location updates.

Comment: I want switch from significant location to standard location service. I have called startUpdatingLocation in background. still facing issue

Comment: Your code is looking correct but why you are using MonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Comment: I need to implement auto start feature. otherwise the battery will drain if GPS is always on. Working proper if GPS is started in foreground

Comment: you have to use real time location service if you are using location in background mode other wise apple will reject your application. So I advised you to use self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() method.

Comment: We can chat if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for your help. Please update if you find any solution.